# any way to limit "docker logs" output by default?

Tags: docker, linux

**Context***

I forgot to pass the "--tail" options to the "docker logs" command when inspecting a running container. The affected container dumps tens of millions of logs.

The command line was something like:

```
  $ docker logs contianer01 | vim -
```

When executing such line my server becomes completely unresponsive for minutes due to exhaution of free RAM memory with peak loads beyond 60x100%. I loose control of the terminal and ssh connection fails.

***Question***:
Is it any tunning in docker to "fail fast" and forbid such big log outputs in first place (maybe tunning ulimits for the docker daemon in some config file)

***NOTE***: Probably "ulimit", "resource-control" and "linux" tags must be added to this question but I have not enough "reputation".

Comment: For the record, what eats space here is `vim`, you wouldn't have a problem with  `less` for exemple which would stream the output and not load it entirely in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to limit docker logs is to specify limits in docker daemon's config file.

You can put this in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3" 
  }
}
```

and then restart your docker daemon.